# gitignore not removing files

Tags: git, gitignore

I looked into the official documentation

`**/packages` is supposed to remove file/directory packages from being tracked

I tried but without any luck I still see the following:

************NOTE: THESE FILES ARE SYMLINKS***********

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
modified:   src/main/resources/webapp/dart/packages/route_hierarchical
modified:   src/main/resources/webapp/dart/packages/shadow_dom
modified:   src/main/resources/webapp/dart/packages/source_maps
```

my complete .gitignore

```
target/
.idea
.DS_Store
session-store
*.iml
banzai_auth_cache.ser
banzai_rm_cache.ser
**/packages
```

These are the steps:

- I clone the project with git clone I add gitignore and then
- commit/push
- I change the files under packages with "pub get", these files are symlinks
- I see them when I do git status

Okay, I tried add

```
symlinks = false
```

to .git/config, without luck too. I'm looking and I will update my question if I find something

I also tried adding those symlinks one by one to git ignore

Comment: This question has been asked time and time again on the site.

Comment: no it's not the same

Comment: the files are symlinks .... I'm not googling if there is a problem with gitignore and symlinks. maybe that's why

Answer (score 17):

You can try the following commands,

```
git rm --cached .
git add . 
git commit -m "refreshed ignored files."
```

**Edit**

Because of the git syntax you have to point to a folder with the `rm` command.

Comment: `git rm` requires that some path(s) be passed to it: `git rm --cached src/main/resources/webapp/dart/packages/*`. Also, the latter should be enough for the files in question to become ignored. No need to stage anything else or make a commit.

Comment: as the comment said git rm --cached requires file/files and folder location. else this helped solving an issue I have had. :)

Comment: This also works to remove the project's cache: git rm -r --cached ./

Answer (score 3):

.gitignore does not remove files that are already tracked but instead affects which files will be tracked by default when git add is run.  After ignoring some files with .gitignore, you may want to run git rm --cached  on files that are already tracked.

Comment: I actually re-cloned the project, added gitignore and then modified the files! still no luck, can't find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

the symlinks have to be removed and committed first.

```
step 1: add the gitignore
step 2: delete all the symlinks
step 3: commit/push
```

from now on, they won't appear